# Iterating over a closed interval in Swift 2.x

Tags: swift, loops, range, intervals

How do I iterate over every member of a `ClosedInterval` in Swift? For example, this code generates an error:

```
let UInt8_interval: ClosedInterval = UInt8.min ... UInt8.max

for x in UInt8_interval {

    print(x)

}
```

The error says: `Type 'ClosedInterval<UInt8>' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'`.

For certain kinds of bitwise operations, I do want to iterate over 0 through 255 inclusive, and it's important that the type stay `UInt8`. So I can't use a range because the max value of a type can't be part of the range. But I can't figure out how to iterate over a `ClosedInterval`.

Comment: You can use a range in Swift 3.  They fixed that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `stride`?

```
let allUInt8 = UInt8.min.stride(through: UInt8.max, by: 1)

for x in allUInt8 {
    print(x)
}
```

The type of `allUInt8` is `StrideThrough<UInt8>`.

And if you want an array that contains all of `UInt8`:

```
let arrayUInt8 = Array(allUInt8)
```

Comment: Thanks for both this answer and your comment on the question! They're very helpful.

Comment: I think that to create the array the code is `let arrayUInt8 = Array(arrayLiteral: allUInt8)`

Comment: Um, no.  The way I stated creates a `[UInt8]` with all 256 values in it.  Yours creates a `[StrideThrough<UInt8>]` with only 1 item in the array.

Comment: Without `arrayLiteral` I get an error: `Missing argument label "arrayLiteral" in call` and a helpful fixit suggestion to insert "arrayLiteral". The code won't compile. I see your point though, `arrayUInt8.count` is 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: aargh never mind. I figured it out; I was trying to create an array of the `ClosedInterval`, not the Strideable. d'oh

Answer (score 1):

`ClosedInterval` does not conform to `SequenceType` which means it cannot be used in a `for in` as-is.  If you still want to use a `ClosedInterval`, use the range created by the `start` and `end` of the interval:

```
for x in UInt8_interval.start..<UInt8_interval.end {
    print(x)
}
```

Not the greatest solution, but glad Swift 3 addresses things like this as vacawama mentioned.

Comment: That misses `255`, and you can't use `...` because of the range issue in Swift 2.2.

Comment: @vacawama good points.  Would `...` instead of `..<` fix that issue?

Comment: @JAL: No, because before Swift 3, *all* ranges are stored internally as `start ..< end`. Swift 3 distinguishes between `Range` and `ClosedRange` to solve that problem.